# Uploading a CSV file to mysql with Flask, Only first line being uploaded

Tags: python, mysql, csv, file-upload, flask

I am creating a piece of code which will take a csv file and upload the content of the file to a mysql database.

I am conducting this process with Flask, Python 2.7 and MySQL-python==1.2.5.

Currently I have a script (shown below) which fulfils this task, however I can only get the csv file to read/ upload the first row of the csv file.
Any help would be much appreciated.

CSVFILE:

```
date_time,first_name,surname,address,email
2018/03/23 12:09:10,Steve,Jones,UK,SteveJones@hotmail.com
2018/03/23 12:12:20,Jack,Flipper,UK,JackFlipper@hotmail.com
2018/03/23 12:14:30,Rebecca,Fletcher,France,RebeccaFletcher@hotmail.com
2018/03/23 12:15:10,Aby,Jones,Italy,AbyJones@hotmail.com
```

PYTHON:

```
import os
import io
import csv
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for,flash
from flask_login import current_user, login_required
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, DATA
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from . import upload_csv_blueprint
from .. import db
from .. models import details

@upload_csv_blueprint.route('/upload_csv_layout', methods=['POST' , 'GET'])
@login_required
def upload_csv_layout():

    return render_template('upload_csv.html', title='upload_csv')

@upload_csv_blueprint.route('/upload_csv', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_file():
  if request.method == 'POST':
      csvfile = request.files['file']

      reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
      data = [row for row in reader]
      for row in data:
          date_time_store = row['date_time']
          first_name_store = row['first_name']
          surname_store = row['surname']
          address_store = row['address']
          email_store = row['email']

          query = details(date_time = date_time_store,first_name=first_name_store,surname=surname_store,address=address_store,email=email_store)
          db.session.add(query)
          db.session.commit()
          return('Did it work?')
  else:
      return redirect(url_for('upload_csv.upload_csv_layout'))
```

HTML OF PAGE:

```
{% import 'bootstrap/utils.html' as utils %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}
{% extends '/advanced_banner.html' %}
    {% block body %}
      <title> Upload CSV </title>
            <form method=POST enctype=multipart/form-data action='/upload_csv'>
                <input type='file' name='file' class='UCSV_FileInput'></input>
                    <button type='submit' value='Upload'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class='flash_holding_box'>
            <div class='flash'><b> Action Log </b> <br>{{utils.flashed_messages()}}</div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Understand that my imports are a bit wacky, but been trying a few different techniques.

Comment: Try indenting the two lines below the for loop, e.g. the query and add. Possibly also the commit.

Comment: Martin's right but if that was the problem your script should have imported only the last row of the file, isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry about such a long wait for reply, been a busy week and have not really had a chance to try things out. I am afraid that @MartinEvans theory did not work. As it was already indented, must of just been a coping error, indenting further throws up indenting errors.

Comment: @Hugo any ideas ?

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question to show the correct indentation then.

Comment: no problem, easily done :)

Comment: Not sure but if you change this `data = [row for row in reader]
      for row in data:` to `for row in reader:` and then try printing the row to make sure your loop is correct.

Comment: Was not the issue however did lead me to figure out that with a return statement this is required:  return(',  '.join(row)), Just got to put the .join into mysql, seems to be that the sql only runs once and then stops.